# Core Data Update is Inserting new Row

Tags: swift, core-data

When I try to update an existing row in core data using the **updateData()** function, it always creates a new entry in core data, instead of updating an already existing one.

Am I doing something wrong here? Or do I need to first delete the original entry then create a new one?

```swift
func updateData(updatedReminder: AReminder) throws {

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "AReminder")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %@", updatedReminder.id! as CVarArg)

    do {
        if let fetchResult = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [NSManagedObject] {
            let aReminderObject = fetchResult[0] as! AReminder

            aReminderObject.label = updatedReminder.label
            aReminderObject.isActive = updatedReminder.isActive
            aReminderObject.time = updatedReminder.time
            aReminderObject.daysOfWeek = updatedReminder.daysOfWeek

            try managedContext.save()
        }
    } catch {
        print("could not update\n\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this function's caller get `updatedReminder` to pass in?

Comment: You don't need to fetch since you already have the object in memory, just call managedContext.save()